# Solving Simple Coupled Nonlinear DE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the simple system,

$$
\dot{x} = \alpha (\beta-x)\\
\dot{y} = x(\delta-y)
$$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\delta$ are constants.

Can someone give references on how to solve them?

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Answer (score 3):

Solve the first equation first, which is decoupled from the second one

$$
x(t) = \beta + A e^{-\alpha t}
$$

Replace it in the second one so you get

$$
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t} = (\beta + Ae^{-\alpha t})(\delta + y)
$$

Which is a linear equation in $y$, can you take it from here?

Comment: ah yes! was being stupid... :D